# Как скрыть меню при переходе на фрагмент

Tags: android

В `NavigationDrawer`(главная активность которая включает в себя фрагмент) у меня создается `menu`

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_drawer, menu);
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
```

Мне необходимо чтобы при переходе на фрагмент(основной,который появляется как только `NavigationDrawer` отрабатывает), открывающееся меню(которое на скрине обведено красным) скрывалось и появлялось лишь при переходе на остальные фрагменты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В фрагменте объявляем о желании изменять меню активити и собственно вносим изменения:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        // собственное меню фрагмента, если оно нужно
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment, menu);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // скрываем элемент с ID - menu_action_setting
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_action_settings).setVisible(false);

        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

*menu_action_setting* - ID элемента меню из Activity, который надо удалить